# Trouble with prestashop zip code

Tags: prestashop, zipcode, postal-code

I have a problem with my Prestashop zip code. 
It always says it's invalid when you pay as a guest (with an account it seems to work fine) for now i have turned zip code completely off. This is lowering sales so i hope that one of you has an answer.

Thanks in advance,

Lex

Comment: core version? address country?

Comment: it's already fixed. Thanks anyway.